# Laravel roles on routes

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a Laravel 5.2 application using the Auth functionality provided by Laravel. For roles and permissions I'm using [laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission). I have defined 3 roles: admin, seller, buyer.

I was looking for a solution to be able to specify a role per route. So that I have a group of routes only accessible for user with role 'admin', a group of routes only accessible for user with role 'seller' and a group of routes only accessible to users with role 'buyer'.

I was thinking to define a separate middleware for admin, buyer and seller and use that for the routes. Or is the better way to define 1 middleware 'roles' that differentiates between the roles? Any better ways?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a middleware that takes parameters. Then you can do something like

```
'middleware' => 'role:role_name',
```

a single middleware with params passed should do fine